# Add a new row to to csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I am new to Powershell. I have a directory full of CSV files. I have to read each row in the csv files and take certain actions. If any value in the target column is equal to "XXXXXXX", I need to copy the whole row to a new row with the target field as "NEWVALUE". I don't want to append the input file but create a clone of input and do changes in that. Not sure how to do this with Powershell.

Example and sample input & Output files:
Input file can have any number of rows but only 9 columns

> Header: column1,column2.....column9

> Row1: abc, xyz, 123,,,,,999,done

> Row2: kkk,rww, zzz,888,111,,,,done

> Row3: xxx,rww, zzz,888,111,,XXXXXXX,,done

> Row4: yyy,rww, zzz,888,111,,,,done

> Row5: rrr,rww, zzz,888,111,,,,done

Output file should add an additional row with "NEWVALUE". Rest of the fields are same as copied row

> Header: column1,column2.....column9

> Row1: abc, xyz, 123,,,,,999,done

> Row2: kkk,rww, zzz,888,111,,,,done

> Row3: xxx,rww, zzz,888,111,,XXXXXXX,,done

> Row4: xxx,rww, zzz,888,111,,NEWVALUE,,done

> Row5: yyy,rww, zzz,888,111,,,,done

> Row6: rrr,rww, zzz,888,111,,,,done

Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What worked and what didn’t work? Please add any code you’ve already written, and maybe have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Apologies for being a bit blunt, but @mclayton is correct. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Generally here, it's expected that SO is the last stop on your journey to a solution, not the first place you go. It's expected that you've researched and attempted this already yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i would convert .csv to excel and make a conditional formatting or if function.

if b1 = "xxxx"; b4=b1;blabla

then reconvert to .csv again.